# Show HTML from JS in the source code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to show on **page source** ( **ctrl+U** )  the HTML elements I've added in JavaScript and jQuery codes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No.**

The page source will always show you the HTML retrieved from the server.

Inspect the generated DOM tree instead, e.g. with Firebug (Firefox) or the Developer Tools (Chrome, Safari).

Answer (score 2):

Nope, you just can see it on you firebug, developer tools, etc...

Answer (score 0):

No, but ever modern browser has a way/extension to see the *current* sourcecode (actually, the DOM tree), i.e. including everything done by JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the browser (i like chrome / firefox / safari for this) you want to look at developer tools.  In firefox you can use firebug, in chrome it's Developer Tools and in Safari you have to turn on Developer menu through preferences.  In all three cases, you want to look at the DOM inspector.